# Use Nagios To Monitor MS SQL Server Database Growth

Tags: sql-server, nagios

i am using Nagios to monitor various things across our network, and i would like to use it to chart the growth of a sql server database. There seems to be a few plugins around for MS sql server monitoring, but i'm not sure what the best one to use is

Cheers
Luke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer the URL http://www.frank4dd.com/howto/nagios/db-monitoring.htm